# I'm having trouble separating numbers with .'s in between

Tags: java

So, I've been trying to make a program that can change a regular ip (182.66.24.45 as example) to a binary number. I've got  the converting part done, its just me trying to separate the .'s is not doing too well for me. When I try converting the str into an int, then separating the .'s, it just comes out with the errors

```
convertip.java:24: error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
        int[] ipint = Integer.parseInt(ipstr.split("."));
                                                  ^
convertip.java:25: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
        convertbinary(ipint);
                      ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
```

And here is all the code I have

```
    public static void printbinary(int binary[], int id){
        for (int i = id; i>=0; i--){
            System.out.print(binary[i] + "");
        }
    }
    public static void convertbinary(int num){
        int[] binary = new int[35];
        int id = 0;
  
        // Number should be positive
        while (num > 0) {
            binary[id++] = num % 2;
            num = num / 2;
        }
        printbinary(binary, id);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in the ip.");
        String ipstr = ip.nextLine();
        int[] ipint = Integer.parseInt(ipstr.split("."));
        convertbinary(ipint);
    }
```

Comment: `parseInt` expects a String; you are passing it a *array* of strings.

Comment: You need to loop over the string split into an array of it's split parts, then call `convertbinary` on each string. An IP consists of 4 x 8 = 32 bits, it should fit into **one** integer, which you can then print out in hexadecimals. This can all be done using standard calls. Look into `Integer.parseInt` and `ByteBuffer#getInt` for instance.

Comment: how can i convert it Scott Hunter

Comment: What would you convert it *into*?  The whole point of using `split` was to get the individual numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Scott Hunter mentioned in comments, you might need to do following inside `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in the ip.");
        String ipstr = ip.nextLine();
         for (String string : ipstr.split("[.]")) {
                convertbinary(Integer.parseInt(string));
            }
    }
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: none, it just doesnt print the binary

Comment: @MrKomet, updated code, have a look at it once

Comment: also how can you put dots in between the numbers avert converting

Comment: Didn't get your question , please can you rephrase it for me?

Comment: so after it converted all of the numbers, it just prints out `011110110110101010111101101111011`, and i want it to print out the decimals too

Comment: you are converting decimals to binary in `convertbinary` & hence it is printing in binary. Use `System.out.print()` in `convertbinary` before conversion

Comment: can you please explain more? i do not understand

Comment: @MrKomet You can simply do a `System.out.print(".");` whenever you want to print a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly write a method that took a whole array of strings and converted them all to ints, return the `int[]`, but that's not what `Integer.parseInt` does. It takes one `String` and converts it to one `int`.

```
int[] parseInts(String... strings) {
    int[] result = new int[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could then write:

```
String ipstr = "182.66.24.45";
int[] ipint = parseInts(ipstr.split("\\."));
```

And get back an array containing 182, 66, 24, and 45. Of course, if any of the individual strings would throw a NumberFormatException, parseInts will too.